# UNION ALL - ORDER BY, sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, union-all

I get records from 3 tables:

```
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura VAT' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue
    FROM Invoice_vat f
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura korygująca' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue
    FROM Invoice_fks f
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura proforma' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue
    FROM Invoice_pro f
)
ORDER BY date_issue DESC
```

I trying to sort this all with field "date_issue", but this doesn't works... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sorting by "date_issue".  The problem is that it is in a lousy format, where the day of the month is first.  So, the list might start with 1 Jan, but 1 Feb comes before 2 Jan.  I would fix this by using the canonical format YYYY-MM-DD, the ISO standard format for dates.

You can also readily fix this by including the original column in the output:

```
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura VAT' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue,
        f.date_issue as orig_date_issue
    FROM Invoice_vat f
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura korygująca' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue,
        f.date_issue as orig_date_issue
    FROM Invoice_fks f
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        f.id AS id,
        'Faktura proforma' as type,
        DATE_FORMAT(f.date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') AS date_issue,
        f.date_issue as orig_date_issue
    FROM Invoice_pro f
)
ORDER BY orig_date_issue DESC;
```

You can use a subquery if you don't actually want to select the field.

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting by the modified version of `date_issue`, so it will sort as a string, and not a date.

Try doing your formatting for the date last, rather than for each `Union`:

```
Select  ID, 
        Type, 
        DATE_FORMAT(date_issue, '%d.%m.%Y') As Date_Issue
From
(
    (
        SELECT
            f.id AS id,
            'Faktura VAT' as type,
            f.date_issue
        FROM Invoice_vat f
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT
            f.id AS id,
            'Faktura korygująca' as type,
            f.date_issue
        FROM Invoice_fks f
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT
            f.id AS id,
            'Faktura proforma' as type,
            f.date_issue
        FROM Invoice_pro f
    )
) A
ORDER BY A.date_issue DESC
```